# Error trying to connect to a SQL Server using sqlcmd (from Ubuntu command line)?

Tags: sql-server, database, sqlcmd

I am finding some problem trying to connect to a **SQL Server** instance from an Ubuntu machine using **sqlcmd**.

So I installed **sqlcmd** as explained here: https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup-tools?view=sql-server-ver15#ubuntu

The SQL server seems to be reachable because I can successfully connect to the 1433 port of its IP via Telnet.

Then I tried to connect to one of my database on this server, in this way:

```
./sqlcmd -S MY_SERVER_IP\ESB_WSO2_USER_DB
```

Where **MY_SERVER_IP** is the IP of this server and **ESB_WSO2_USER_DB** is the name of a database on this server.

The problem is that I am obtaining the following message error as output:

> Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Login timeout
>   expired.
>  Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
>   : TCP Provider: Error code 0x2AFA.
>  Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC
>   Driver 17 for SQL Server : A network-related or instance-specific
>   error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server.
>   Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is
>   correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
>   For more information see SQL Server Books Online.

So what could be the problem? Is it something that could be related to my **sqlcmd** installation (maybe some missconfiguration) or something related to my connection string? or something related to the **SQL Server** database?

The message says that maybe the SQL Server maybe is not allowing external connection but...if so...why Telnet connection works fine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-S MY_SERVER_IP\ESB_WSO2_USER_DB` means the IP of the server, and the **name** of the instance. Windows Hosts can run multiple instances of SQL Server, and when they do, latter instances need to be given a different name to the default instance name (`MSSQLSERVER`) and run on a different port. As a result you can specify the name afterwards, rather than the port (if you have named servers running). For example `SRVSQLHost\DevInstance` would connect the to instance `DevInstance` on the server `SRVSQLHost`; **not** the database `DevInstance` on the instance `MSSQLSERVER` on the host `SRVSQLHost`.

You pass the name of the database using the `-d` switch. If you run simply `sqlcmd` (in Bash, not Powershell, where you need to use `sqlcmd -?`) you'll see the input switches:

```sh
:~$ sqlcmd
Microsoft (R) SQL Server Command Line Tool
Version 17.4.0001.1 Linux
Copyright (c) 2012 Microsoft. All rights reserved.

usage: sqlcmd            [-U login id]          [-P password]
  [-S server or Dsn if -D is provided] 
  [-H hostname]          [-E trusted connection]
  [-N Encrypt Connection][-C Trust Server Certificate]
  [-d use database name] [-l login timeout]     [-t query timeout]
  [-h headers]           [-s colseparator]      [-w screen width]
  [-a packetsize]        [-e echo input]        [-I Enable Quoted Identifiers]
  [-c cmdend]
  [-q "cmdline query"]   [-Q "cmdline query" and exit]
  [-m errorlevel]        [-V severitylevel]     [-W remove trailing spaces]
  [-u unicode output]    [-r[0|1] msgs to stderr]
  [-i inputfile]         [-o outputfile]
  [-k[1|2] remove[replace] control characters]
  [-y variable length type display width]
  [-Y fixed length type display width]
  [-p[1] print statistics[colon format]]
  [-R use client regional setting]
  [-K application intent]
  [-M multisubnet failover]
  [-b On error batch abort]
  [-D Dsn flag, indicate -S is Dsn] 
  [-X[1] disable commands, startup script, environment variables [and exit]]
  [-x disable variable substitution]
  [-? show syntax summary]
```

*Note that some switches available on Windows Powershell are not available in Bash and Powershell for Linux; such as parameters.*

So, for what you have you want:

```
sqlcmd -S MY_SERVER_IP -d ESB_WSO2_USER_DB -U YOUR_LOGIN_NAME
```

*(I assume you need to pass the `-U` switch, unless you* have *configured kerboros on your Ubuntu instance, but you didn't mention it, so I assumed not. Note that the `LOGIN` for `-U` must be a SQL Authentication login, not an AD login.)*