# Login failed when I trying to connect to a SQL Server using sqlcmd (from Ubuntu command line)?

Tags: sql-server, database, rdbms, sqlcmd

I am finding some problem trying to connect to a SQL Server instance from an Ubuntu machine using sqlcmd. The SQL server instance run on another server that is an always on MS-SQL Server cluster.

So I installed sqlcmd as explained here: https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup-tools?view=sql-server-ver15#ubuntu

The SQL server seems to be reachable because I can successfully connect to the 1433 port of its IP via Telnet.

Then I tried to connect to one of my database on this server, in this way:

```
./sqlcmd -S MY-IP-ADDRESS -d ESB_WSO2_USER_DB -U datacenter\\wso2DBAdmin
```

Where:

- **ESB_WSO2_USER_DB** is the DB name
- **datacenter\wso2DBAdmin** is the domain\username

It ask me the password, I insert the password (pretty sure that the credential should be ok) but I am obtaining this error message:

> Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Login failed
>   for user 'datacenter\wso2DBAdmin'..

Assuming that username and password are correct: what could be the problem? Is it something that could be related to my sqlcmd installation (maybe some missconfiguration), or the driver? or something related to my connection string? or something related to the SQL Server database?

Comment: `datacenter\\wso2DBAdmin` isn't a valid SQL Authentication login. So that's why.

Comment: @Larnu I also tried without domain (only wso2DBAdmin) but I have always the same problem. There is another way to specify domain?

Comment: From Linux? Not unless you configure Kerboros on it. That is a long and lengthy (and difficult) task. The `-U` is for specifying a SQL Authentication login; but I told you this in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59175653/3484879) I gave you earlier.

Comment: @Larnu ok...so two questions:
1) In theory can I connect without domain?
2) I have to connect a java application to this SQL Server...I will have the same issue?

Comment: *"In theory can I connect without domain"* it's not theory, it's called SQL Authentication; completely different to AD authentication. *"I have to connect a java application to this SQL Server...I will have the same issue?"* not if you use SQL Authentication.

Comment: [Authentication in SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/authentication-in-sql-server)